# Let @Security annotation take precedence over ParamConverter

Tags: php, symfony

I have an action like:

```
/**
 * @Security("is_granted('ROLE_USER_EDITOR')")
 * @Route("/{email}")
 * @Method("GET")
 */
public function getAction(User $user)
```

The problem is that the ParamConverter takes precedence over the `@Security` annotation.

If I am not authorized and supply an existing email, I get redirected to the login page. This is expected and correct.
But when I am not authorized and supply an non-existing email, I get a 404 saying that the `User` cannot be found.

I would think that authorization checking is more important than parameter converting.
**How do I let the `Security` annotation take precedence over the Param Converter?**

Comment: I think it isn't what you want but the access_control in `security.yml` file are checked before the param converter. I up-voted your question, waiting for a response too :)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but then I would rather fetch the user myself.

Comment: As a side note, the precedence of the `Param Converter` annotation over the `Security` one is needed if you use the converted parameters in the expression given to `@Security`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could avoid getting a 404 by adding a `null` default value to the `$user` parameter.

```
/**
 * @Security("is_granted('ROLE_USER_EDITOR')")
 * @Route("/{email}")
 * @Method("GET")
 */
getAction(User $user = null) {
    if ($user === null) {
        return $this->createNotFoundException();
    }
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Both `@ParamConverter` and `@Entity` are [subscribing](https://github.com/sensiolabs/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/blob/v5.1.6/EventListener/ParamConverterListener.php#L119) to the `CONTROLLER` kernel event while `@Security` and `@IsGranted` annotations are [subscribing](https://github.com/sensiolabs/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/blob/v5.1.6/EventListener/SecurityListener.php#L135) to the `CONTROLLER_ARGUMENTS` kernel event which is [dispatched after `CONTROLLER`](https://github.com/symfony/http-kernel/blob/4.0/HttpKernel.php#L137):

> The `CONTROLLER_ARGUMENTS` event occurs once controller arguments have been resolved.

Consequently, `@Security` will always be executed after `@ParamConverter` due to [the order of the events](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/http_kernel.html#the-workflow-of-a-request) they are subscribed to. As I said in my comment, this order of execution is needed to allow the use of converted parameters in your security checks (as presented [here](https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/annotations/security.html#isgranted)).

---

Thus, to avoid the behaviour you described, I guess you will have to simply write things in a different way. As @goto pointed out, you could add a default value for `user` or you could also retrieve the user yourself and drop automated parameter converting entirely for this use case.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and links. Very helpful.